# Как проверть SOAP запрос и найти ошибку?

Tags: java, android, soap

Помогите разобраться как проверить запрос и найти проблему? У меня есть

- URL
- Header
- Body
- XML шаблон запроса

Но с сервера мне постоянно возвращается error 400

Вроде все составлено правильно, не могу понять в чем может быть ошибка и как можно понять это?

Насколько я понимаю это может быть дело либо в URL либо в header

Но URL вроде как верный , насчет header не уверен и не знаю как проверить

Если что то забыл спрашивайте

это мой реквест XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <tem:LoginCheck>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <tem:TaskReq>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:DeviceImei>DEVICE_IMEI</tem:DeviceImei>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:DeviceModel>DEVICE_MODEL</tem:DeviceModel>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:ApplicationVersion>APPLICATION_VERSION</tem:ApplicationVersion>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:UserId>USER_ID</tem:UserId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:PassCode>PASS_CODE</tem:PassCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:PlanningDate>PlanningDate</tem:PlanningDate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:TaskReqDetails>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:TaskNumber>?</tem:TaskNumber>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:TaskStatus>?</tem:TaskStatus>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:TaskType>?</tem:TaskType>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:TaskAsmType>?</tem:TaskAsmType>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:TafnitASM>?</tem:TafnitASM>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:InputASM>?</tem:InputASM>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:DriverName>?</tem:DriverName>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:DriverSign>cid:643235793819</tem:DriverSign>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:TaskRemark>?</tem:TaskRemark>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PrintMDBK>?</tem:PrintMDBK>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PrinterMDBK>?</tem:PrinterMDBK>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PrinterMAIN>?</tem:PrinterMAIN>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:SendMail>?</tem:SendMail>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:TaskSkuList>
                    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                    <tem:TaskSkuDetails>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SKU>?</tem:SKU>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuDesc>?</tem:SkuDesc>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:QNT>?</tem:QNT>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:InStorQNT>?</tem:InStorQNT>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PlannedQNT>?</tem:PlannedQNT>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:AsmType>?</tem:AsmType>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:TaskLine>?</tem:TaskLine>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Asm>?</tem:Asm>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:AsmLn>?</tem:AsmLn>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuMessage>?</tem:SkuMessage>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuStatus>?</tem:SkuStatus>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuSerial>?</tem:SkuSerial>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SerialNumber>?</tem:SerialNumber>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuLocation>?</tem:SkuLocation>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuPrintMDBK>?</tem:SkuPrintMDBK>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuScanned>?</tem:SkuScanned>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuTimeStamp>?</tem:SkuTimeStamp>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SibatILikut>?</tem:SibatILikut>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PatternMatchList>
                            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                            <tem:PatternMatch>
                                <!--Optional:-->
                                <tem:PatternMatch>?</tem:PatternMatch>
                            </tem:PatternMatch>
                        </tem:PatternMatchList>
                    </tem:TaskSkuDetails>
                </tem:TaskSkuList>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:TaskSkuListCounted>
                    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                    <tem:TaskSkuDetails>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SKU>?</tem:SKU>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuDesc>?</tem:SkuDesc>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:QNT>?</tem:QNT>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:InStorQNT>?</tem:InStorQNT>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PlannedQNT>?</tem:PlannedQNT>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:AsmType>?</tem:AsmType>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:TaskLine>?</tem:TaskLine>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Asm>?</tem:Asm>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:AsmLn>?</tem:AsmLn>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuMessage>?</tem:SkuMessage>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuStatus>?</tem:SkuStatus>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuSerial>?</tem:SkuSerial>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SerialNumber>?</tem:SerialNumber>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuLocation>?</tem:SkuLocation>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuPrintMDBK>?</tem:SkuPrintMDBK>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuScanned>?</tem:SkuScanned>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SkuTimeStamp>?</tem:SkuTimeStamp>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SibatILikut>?</tem:SibatILikut>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PatternMatchList>
                            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                            <tem:PatternMatch>
                                <!--Optional:-->
                                <tem:PatternMatch>?</tem:PatternMatch>
                            </tem:PatternMatch>
                        </tem:PatternMatchList>
                    </tem:TaskSkuDetails>
                </tem:TaskSkuListCounted>
            </tem:TaskReqDetails>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:IncludeItems>?</tem:IncludeItems>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:SoftSolutionsID>?</tem:SoftSolutionsID>
        </tem:TaskReq>
    </tem:LoginCheck>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Исходник закачал сюда так как длина привышает допустимую в вопросе

http://dropmefiles.com/9kcAO

Comment: Вы забыли приложить исходники самого SOAP запроса + его шаблон

Comment: @Barmaley Приложил шаблон и исходники. Если еще что то забыл говорите

Comment: Одно могу сказать - ненавижу SOAP :(

Comment: @Barmaley Я первый раз с ним работаю и тоже не пойму почему его используют в этом проекте( У вас есть какие нибудь догадки как можно проверить где ошибка? Я написал на сервер, чтоб посмотрели что к ним приходит и почему возвращается ошибка,  пока жду, но я так понял, что чтоб найти ее на сервере тоже нужно посидеть

Comment: Нужна трассировка ошибки со стороны сервера